# RegEx for alphanumeric text strings up to special patterns

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings with specific format and just need part of those elements.

#### Input

```
my_list = ['The Price Is Right S47E141 720p WEB x264-W4F', 'Breakthrough-The Ideas That Changed the World S01E01 480p x264-mSD',
'The Kid Who Would Be King 2019 DVDR-JFKDVD', 'American Housewife S03E18 Phone Free Day 1080p AMZN WEB-DL DDP5 1 H 264-NTb',
'VICE News Tonight 2019 04 16 720p AMZN WEB-DL DDP2 0 H 264-monkee','The Flash 2014 S05E18 Godspeed 720p AMZN WEB-DL DDP5 1 H 264-NTb',
'The Rachel Maddow Show 2019 04 16 720p MNBC WEB-DL AAC2 0 x264-BTW','Lets Make A Deal 2009 S10E142 XviD-AFG']
```

#### RegEx attempt:

```
try:
    try:
        def get_rls(t):
            w = re.match(".*\d{4} \d{2} \d{2} ", t)
            # w = re.match(".*S\d+E\d+", t)
            if not w: raise Exception("Error For Regular Expression")
            return w.group(0)

        regular_case = [my_list ]
        for w in regular_case:
            Regular_part = get_rls(w)
            print(">>>> Movie Regular Part contains Year/Mon/Day : ", Regular_part)         
    except:
        try:
            def get_rls(t):
                # w = re.match(".*\d ", t)
                w = re.match(".*S\d+E\d+", t)
                if not w: raise Exception("Error For Regular Expression")
                return w.group(0)


            regular_case = [my_list ]
            for w in regular_case:
                Regular_part = get_rls(w)
                print(">>>> Movie Regular Part contains S0E0 : ", Regular_part)             

        except:
            def get_rls(t):
                w = re.match(".*\d{4} ", t)
                # w = re.match(".*S\d+E\d+", t)
                if not w: raise Exception("Error For Regular Expression")
                return w.group(0)


            regular_case = [my_list ]
            for w in regular_case:
                Regular_part = get_rls(w)
                print(">>>> Movie Regular Part contains Year : ", Regular_part)

except:
    print(">>>> Weard Release Name! Pass the Regular part ")
    Regular_part = my_list
```

The problem is, my regex codes just can get one element and decides to use which RegEx is useful and print the regular expression, and I need the RegEx code able to get the list and work on every single elements, for example get first element and decide which one is good.

The best result should be like following list:

```
my_list = ['The Price Is Right S47E141', 'Breakthrough-The Ideas That Changed the World S01E01',
'The Kid Who Would Be King 2019 DVDR-JFKDVD', 'American Housewife S03E18 ',
'VICE News Tonight 2019 04 16','The Flash 2014 S05E18',
'The Rachel Maddow Show 2019 04 16 ','Lets Make A Deal 2009 S10E142']
```

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/3fLai5/1) is not the full right answer, but maybe it would help you to figure out a general way to process your text inputs. Maybe, RegEx would not be the best way to solve this problem:

```
^.+?(?:[SE0-9]+)|(?:\s[A-Z]{4}\-[A-Z]{1,})|(?:.+[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2})|(?:\s[SE0-9]{6,10})
```

[image]

`SE` patterns and `date` patterns are simple for this RegEx. The problem you might be facing is the random years such as `2014`, `2009` and `2019`, which you might take into account.